# Creating a Word Document and returning to the user in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ms-word

I need to create a word document in memory and return it to the web user.
I have the OfficeOpenXml but I just can't figure out a decent way of creating this word document to return to the user. And I can't find much out there on how to do this.
There has to be a simple way of doing this.
When I explore the OfficeOpenXml, I just see a whole bunch of Excell stuff and nothing about word.
Any help or links to tutorials would be great. Thank you!
This is all in asp.net MVC using C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sample to create Word document http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb497758.aspx using OpenXML SDK (download from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0&displaylang=en). For in-memory manipulation check out this blog - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/12/10/working-with-in-memory-open-xml-documents.aspx

When you created document you need to return it as response setting content-disposition header appropriately - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, you can send it down as a file download.  Basically you create the file and write it's binary data to the response.  The only thing that you need to really do is change the response headers to tell the browser it is a DOC and not HTML.